# Flutter - widget class in ternary operator

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, conditional-operator

I want to use a ternary operator to switch between a Column and a Row, while having only one list of children, I know there are many approaches like `condition ? Row() : Column()` but that would require typing the children list for each widget, I am aware I could have the list of children as a variable and just pass it to both, **but what I am looking for specifically if the idea of the code below is possible in anyway ?**

```
(condition ? Row : Column)(
   children: [],
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Row` and `Column` are both children of `Flex`, so just use a `Flex` widget with the `direction` argument set to either `Axis.horizontal` or `Axis.vertical`

```
Flex(
  direction: condition ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal, 
  children: []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your answer would indeed work, but I probably asked the question to know whether If I could write a ternary operator the way I presented it ?

Comment: @Nerox The way you have it written is not valid Dart syntax. So no, you could not write it the way you have it above. While I see what you are trying to do there, it would be an uncommon way to construct an object. It goes against convention which would itself conflict with dart's adherence to the principle of least astonishment. Unfortunately I don't think it likely that syntax like this will be supported.